# Sacar el resultado de un listado e imprimido en un JTextArea

Tags: java, eclipse

mi metodo *"buscadorEnTextArea"*, no funciona, solo me imprime el ultimo string que dice Fin, no el listado de archivos. Cuando selecciono la carpeta, y supuestamante en el metodo buscadorEnTextArea me lista todos los archivos contenidos en ella y me los imprime en un JTextArea, los resultados no me salen en el JTextArea. Solo imprime el ultimo fin.

Uso:

> eclipse Oxygen 64bits
>
> java 1.8.

¿Alguien detecta donde tengo el error?. Quizas sea facil el error, pero estoy empezando con java y cualquier ayuda es bienvenida. Gracias.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class VentanaPreguntaPrimera extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textFieldPlaylist;
    private JTextField textFieldCarpeta;
    private JTextArea textArea;
    private Fichero fichero; 
    private Carpeta carpeta; 
    private String tituloVentana = "H#02 - lista de ficheros en carpeta";

    public Fichero getFichero() {
        return fichero;
    }

    public void setFichero(Fichero fichero) {
        this.fichero = fichero;
    }

    public Carpeta getCarpeta() {
        return carpeta;
    }

    public void setCarpeta(Carpeta carpeta) {
        this.carpeta = carpeta;
    }

    public JTextField getTextFieldPlaylist() {
        return textFieldPlaylist;
    }

    public void setTextFieldPlaylist(JTextField textFieldPlaylist) {
        this.textFieldPlaylist = textFieldPlaylist;
    }

    public JTextField getTextFieldCarpeta() {
        return textFieldCarpeta;
    }

    public void setTextFieldCarpeta(JTextField textFieldCarpeta) {
        this.textFieldCarpeta = textFieldCarpeta;
    }

    public JTextArea getTextArea() {
        return textArea;
    }

    public void setTextArea(JTextArea textArea) {
        this.textArea = textArea;
    }


    public VentanaPreguntaPrimera() {

        // Parametros asociados a la ventana
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 850, 340);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        setTitle(tituloVentana); // titulo de la ventana que saco

    
        textFieldPlaylist = new JTextField();
        textFieldPlaylist.setToolTipText("Inserta la ruta del ficherot");
        // el de arriba
        textFieldPlaylist.setBounds(52, 26, 609, 20);
        contentPane.add(textFieldPlaylist);
        textFieldPlaylist.setColumns(10);

        /* JTextField que es el campo de la ruta de la carpeta */
        textFieldCarpeta = new JTextField();
        textFieldCarpeta.setToolTipText("Inserta la ruta de la carpeta");
        // el de abajo
        textFieldCarpeta.setBounds(52, 250, 609, 20);
        contentPane.add(textFieldCarpeta);
        textFieldCarpeta.setColumns(10);

        // boton del playlist
        JButton btnSeleccionar = new JButton("fichero ?");
        btnSeleccionar.setBounds(688, 25, 109, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnSeleccionar);

        // boton de la carpeta
        JButton btnSeleccionarCarpeta = new JButton("CARPETA ?");
        btnSeleccionarCarpeta.setBounds(688, 250, 109, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnSeleccionarCarpeta);

    
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.setBounds(52, 76, 760, 156);

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scroll.setBounds(52, 76, 760, 156);
        contentPane.add(scroll);

        // boton del playlist su ActionListener
        btnSeleccionar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                /*
                 * una vez pulsa el boton, llamo al metodo que saca una ventana de busqueda del
                 * archivo
                 */
                creaVentanaElegirFichero();
            }
        });

        // boton del buscar carpeta su ActionListener
        btnSeleccionarCarpeta.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                /*
                 * una vez pulsa el boton, llamo al metodo que saca una ventana de busqueda del
                 * archivo
                 */
                creaVentanaElegirCarpeta();
            }
        });

    }

    /* metodo que saca una ventana de busqueda de archivo */
    public void creaVentanaElegirFichero() {
        
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.setCurrentDirectory(new File("c:/p"));

        int seleccion = fc.showOpenDialog(contentPane);

        // Si el usuario, pincha en aceptar
        if (seleccion == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

            File ficheroTemporal = fc.getSelectedFile();
        
            fichero = new Fichero(ficheroTemporal);

            // Escribe la ruta del fichero seleccionado en el campo de texto
            textFieldPlaylist.setText(fichero.getFichero().getAbsolutePath());

            
            try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(fichero.getFichero())) {
                String cadena = "";
                int valor = fr.read();
                while (valor != -1) {
                    cadena = cadena + (char) valor;
                    valor = fr.read();
                }
                textArea.setText(cadena); // aqui lo imprime en TextArea
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    /* metodo que saca ventana de busqueda de archivos en directorio */
    public void creaVentanaElegirCarpeta() {


        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.setCurrentDirectory(new File("c:/p"));
        fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        int seleccion = fc.showOpenDialog(contentPane);

        if (seleccion == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

            File carpetaTemporal;
            carpetaTemporal = fc.getSelectedFile();
            carpeta = new Carpeta(carpetaTemporal);

            // Escribe la ruta del fichero seleccionado en textField
            textFieldCarpeta.setText(carpeta.getCarpeta().getAbsolutePath());

            // este si funciona, me lo saca por consola
            carpeta.buscador(carpeta.getCarpeta().getAbsolutePath());

            // ahora pruebo a sacarlos al JTextArea - NO FUNCIONA!
            carpeta.buscadorEnTextArea(carpeta.getCarpeta().getAbsolutePath(), textArea);
        }
    }

}



/*
 * clase donde meto la ruta o carpeta donde buscar y hace operaciones
 */

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Carpeta {

    public File carpeta; // carpeta donde busco

    public File getCarpeta() {
        return carpeta;
    }

    public void setCarpeta(File carpeta) {
        this.carpeta = carpeta;
    }

    // constructor por defecto
    public Carpeta() {
    }

    public Carpeta(File carpeta) {
        this.carpeta = carpeta;
    }

    
    public void buscador(String queCarpeta) {
        
        String path = queCarpeta;

        String files;
        File folder = new File(path);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {

            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
                if (files.endsWith(".txt") || files.endsWith(".TXT")) {
                    System.out.println(files);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Fin");
    }

    
    public void buscadorEnTextArea(String queCarpeta, JTextArea textArea) {

        // Aquí la carpeta que queremos explorar, por ejemplo:
        String path = queCarpeta;

        String files;
        File folder = new File(path);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {

            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
                if (files.endsWith(".txt") || files.endsWith(".TXT")) {
                    textArea.setText(files); // aqui lo imprime en TextArea... PERO NO FUNCIONA
                }
            }
        }
        textArea.setText("Fin"); // le añado fin - Este si funciona
    }
}
```

Comment: Es que al hacer esto en el bucle: `textArea.setText(files);` en cada iteracción reemplazará los nombres de archivo. Debes concatenar en una variable, por ejemplo, un Stringbuilder y luego, fuera del bucle, hacer un `textArea.setText(todosLosArchivosConcatenados);`

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es que al hacer esto en el bucle: `textArea.setText(files);` en cada iteracción reemplazará los nombres de archivo. Debes concatenar en una variable, por ejemplo, un Stringbuilder y luego, fuera del bucle, imprimir todos los nombres de archivos recogidos dentro del bucle.

Si la palabra `Fin` también debe ir al final de los nombres de archivos, debes incluirla dentro de la variable `sb`.

Es que cuando haces `setText` borras el contenido que haya en el TextField, reemplanzádolo por el valor actual.

Por ejemplo:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {

        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
            if (files.endsWith(".txt") || files.endsWith(".TXT")) {
                sb.append(files); 
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator()); //Salto de línea 

            }
        }
    }
//Fin también debe incluirse en el sb, si quieres que aparezca al final.
sb.append("Fin");

//Imprimes todos los archivos dentro del StringBuilder 
textArea.setText(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, lo has explicado muy bien y el ejemplo es perfecto.